# Insert and Update sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in database: `users` and `user_settings`.

In `users` table I have primary key column as `user_id` and other columns such as `first_name` and `last_name`.

In `user_setting` table there is 4 columns:`user_id`,`locale`,`value_name` and `value`. There is different `user_id` records and some user_id may occur several times or may not occur once.

I want to add to `user_setting` table, records for each `user_id` which `value_name` is equal to 'first_name' and `valee` is from `users` table `first_name` column. Also do the same for `last_name`.

In other words, I want to add in `user_setting` table for each `user_id` in columns `locale` , `value_name` , `value` these values: ('en_us' , 'first_name' , first_name column from `users` table) and ('en_us' , 'last_name' , last_name column from `users` table).
For example in `users` table if there is a user_id: 10 with first_name = 'john' and last_name = 'smith' I want to add these two records to `user_setting` table:
(10,'en_US','first_name','john') and (10,'en_US','last_name','smith')

What is query for this task? Thanks a lot

Comment: This seems a weirdly contrived example / question - assignment by chance? can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding site. Show us what you have tried so far and didn't work and then we can help you

Comment: Are there any such records already in the user settings table?  Or can you naively insert these rows without checking if they already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very naive solution would just be to select the fields you want and insert them in to the other table...

```
INSERT INTO
  user_Setting (
    user_id,
    locale,
    value_name,
    value
  )

SELECT
  user.id,
  'en_us',
  'first_name',
  user.first_name
FROM
  user

UNION ALL

SELECT
  user.id,
  'en_us',
  'last_name',
  user.last_name
FROM
  user
;
```

This assumes there are no such records in this table already, so you don't need to make any checks before you run the `INSERT`.